# Python: sort tab-separated key in dict by both columns

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with tab separated keys.

```
d = {}
d["1\t1"] = "abc"
d["10\t1"] = "def"
d["1\t10"] = "ghi"
d["2\t5"] = "xyz"
d["1\t4"] = 0
```

How can I sort these keys after first and second column?

I cannot use this

```
for s in sorted(d):
    print s
```

because my keys are strings.

I want to return this:

```
1  1
1  4
1  10
2  5
10 1
```

How can this be achieved? I am not even sure if dictionaries are the right data structures.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not doing `d[1,1] = "abc"`?

Comment: Actually only because I did not think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i assume the second column means after \t

```
sorted(d.items(),key= lambda x: (int(x[0].split('\t')[0]),int(x[0].split('\t')[-1])))
```

output:

```
[('1\t1', 'abc'), ('1\t4', 0), ('1\t10', 'ghi'), ('2\t5', 'xyz'), ('10\t1', 'def')]
```

print out:

```
for k,_ in sorted(d.items(),key= lambda x: (int(x[0].split('\t')[0]),int(x[0].split('\t')[-1]))):
...     print k.split('\t')[0], k.split('\t')[1]
1 1
1 4
1 10
2 5
10 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (and probably much easier solution) for my own problem (thanks Kevin):

```
d = {}
d[1,1] = "abc"
d[10,1] = "def"
d[1,10] = "ghi"
d[2,5] = "xyz"
d[1,4] = 0

for k in sorted(d):
    print(k)
```

Only included small revision of input data.